# Advanced formatting in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file that displays data about jobs and customers. One tab contains a list of bids and their dates of expected completion. This tab has conditional formatting applied that turns the job name font red if a certain cell contains an "X" (meaning "bid but not yet approved/denied"). Another tab pulls data from that list and turns it into a calendar for visual reference. It uses textjoin to create a list of jobs in a cell based on a date of expected completion.

ex:

```
 {=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF('2020 Background Data'!$H$2:$H$301=DATE('2020 Calendar View'!$E$1,'2020 Calendar View'!$B3,'2020 Calendar View'!Z$2),'2020 Background Data'!$I$2:$I$301,""))}
```

That is working fine to list them. However, I have not yet been able to find a way to bring the color along with it when I join it into the comma separated list. I want the text to carry its color along with it so it turns red on the calendar as a quick indicator that we need to call that customer back. Anyone have thoughts?

Comment: You can't with a formula, and is also difficult with vba to only change part of a text string to a different color that will update as the source value changes.

Comment: There is no way to solve that problem interativally. Many colors inside a text demands VBA code.

Comment: Text returned by formulas can't have multiple colors applied.

Comment: In theory it's posible for font color. I've tried the below code. It's not working in Excel 365, 
`Set ce=cells(5,3)
ce.Characters(1, 5).Font.Background = vbBlue`

It shoud change the color in 5 first characters in the cell

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. They are what I thought they would be. I was just hoping that someone would have some really weird answer that could do it. I will continue to check back for a few days just in case.